# What do I have to do in order to execute code in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I've recently started creating notes with org mode... I'd like to understand better what do I have to do in order to execute code with it... Let's say I've created the following `code.org` file:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
  print('test')
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC bash
  echo "test"
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC node
  console.log("test")
#+END_SRC
```

I'd like to be able to execute codes in different programming languages in blocks, I'm not completely sure if that's the right way of doing it, when I try to execute any of those blocks with C-c C-c I receive an error message saying `no org-babel-execute function for python` (node and bash are the same). I've tried to check the command `list-packages` to see if I could install an org mode for them but I didn't find anything specific for org-mode with those languages... What am I missing? Can I execute any programming language that I can execute on the command line with org mode? What extra steps do I need to do in order to start executing code in org mode?

---

#### Different attempt

I've also seen [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17674/39141) in a simular question where the answer instructs to use the following to make a C code execute:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages '((C . t)))
```

Then I tried putting the following on my `.emacs` file:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages '((bash . t)))
```

But it also doesn't work and emacs indicates the error `File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, ob-bash`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using bash you should add `(shell . t)`, otherwise I think you are doing alright.

You can find which 'org babel' files are available by doing `M-x find-library` `RET` `ob-` and pressing TAB.

I guess for node you should use `ob-js` (add `(js . t)`).
You might have to set which executable to use.

You can find customization options using `M-x customize-group` `org-babel`.

Comment: Cool, I managed to execute with those three languages now. However, I can't find `ob-js`, `ob-python` or `ob-shell` with `M-x list-packages` or `M-x find-library ob-` `TAB`... I'm assuming they already exist with the emacs installation. Is there any way of knowing which values exist for me to use inside `org-babel-load-languages`?

Comment: I guess there was a misunderstanding, did you try to press `RET` first after `M-x find-library`? (that's why I added the space between that and `ob-`, I have edited the answer now)