# no org-babel-execute function for sh!

Tags: org-babel

If do `M-x org-babel-execute-src-block` over the code block below, I get "evaluate this bash code block on your system", and then "no org-babel-execute function for bash". Changing `bash` to `shell` or `sh`, same. I found support for `powershell` but not the ones listed. The comment in [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17674/19777) mentions `org-babel-do-load-languages`, but I don't have it. So what then, could I do? Also, why isn't there a key binding for the first command listed?

```
#+begin_src bash :results output
echo "Hello world!"
#+end_src
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `M-x load-library RET ob-shell RET` should allow you to execute the src block. Assuming that works, then add  `(eval-after-load 'org (add-to-list 'org-babel-load-languages '(shell . t)))` to your init file to make it permanent - or customize `org-babel-load-languages` through the customize interface.

Comment: There should be: it is defined in `org.el` so do `(require 'org)` and then try `C-h v org-babel-load-languages` again. With the `eval-after-load` form in your init file, you don't have to worry about when `org` is loaded: when it is, `org-babel-load-languages` will be defined and the form will reset it to add the `ob-shell` backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, do `M-x customize-variable RET org-babel-load-languages`, and proceed as intuitable from the picture. Then go back to the original buffer and [reload the emacs init file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580650/how-can-i-reload-emacs-after-changing-it#2580726). Then do `M-x org-babel-execute-src-block` (or `C-c C-c`) over the code block.

```
#+begin_src shell :results output
echo "Hello world!"
#+end_src
```

Results in this addition to the buffer:

```
#+RESULTS:
: Hello world!
```

[image]